# Count words in an external file using delimiter of a space

Tags: vb.net, count, character, delimiter

I want to calculate the number of words in a text file using a delimiter of a space (" "), however I am struggling.

```
Dim counter = 0
Dim delim = " "
Dim fields() As String
fields = Nothing

Dim line As String
line = Input

While (SR.EndOfStream)
    line = SR.ReadLine()

End While

Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Reading File.. ")

fields = line.Split(delim.ToCharArray())
For i = 0 To fields.Length
    counter = counter + 1

Next

SR.Close()
Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "The word count is {0}", counter)
```

I do not know how to open the file and to get the do this, very confused; would like an explanation so I can edit and understand from it.

Comment: It looks like you will be able to use the first example in the [StreamReader Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2) to help you complete the code you have started.

Comment: Or [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext). You don't need to specify a delimiter if the delimiter is a space (char 32): it's the default separator. That's pretty much all you need.

Comment: @jimi, hi how would i do that the link you provided was in C im new to this so how would i write it inot VB

Comment: It's in `C#`, `C++`, `F#` and `VB.Net`. In the upper-right side of the page you can find the language selector.

Comment: @jimi Dim path As String = "z:test.txt"
        Dim length = Len(path)
        Console.WriteLine(length) , i did this is this correct not working

Comment: `Dim wordsCount As Long = File.ReadAllText("Your File Path").Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length`. Verify that the path you provide is correct.

Comment: @Jimi That would not work correctly if the file has more than one line - although admittedly that is not in the specification as written in the text and only in the code shown.

Comment: @Andrew Morton   Writing in comments has its drawbacks, I forgot a `vbCrLf `: `Dim wordsCount As Long = File.ReadAllText("Your File Path").Split({" "c, vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be reading a file as the source of the data, so let's create a variable to refer to its filename:

```
Dim srcFile = "C:\temp\twolines.txt"
```

As you have shown already, a variable is needed to hold the number of words found:

```
Dim counter = 0
```

To read from the file, a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2) will do the job. Now, we look at the documenation for it (yes, really) and notice that it has a `Dispose` method. That means that we have to *explicitly* dispose of it after we've used it to make sure that no system resources are tied up until the computer is next rebooted (e.g there could be a "[memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)"). Fortunately, there is the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construct to take care of that for us:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(srcFile)
```

And now we want to iterate over the content of the file line-by-line until the end of the file:

```
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
```

Then we want to read a line and find how many items separated by spaces it has:

```
        counter += sr.ReadLine().Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

The `+=` operator is like saying "add n to a" instead of saying "a = a + n". The `{" "c}` is a literal array of the character " "c. The `c` tells it that is a character and not a string of one character. The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` means that if there was text of `"one     two"` then it would ignore the extra spaces.

So, if you were writing a console program, it might look like:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim srcFile = "C:\temp\twolines.txt"
        Dim counter = 0

        Using sr As New StreamReader(srcFile)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                counter += sr.ReadLine().Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
            End While
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(counter)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Any embellishments such as writing out what the number represents or error checking are left up to you.

Answer (score 0):

With Path.Combine you don't have to worry about where the slashes or back slashes go. You can get the path of special folders easily using the Environment class. The File class of System.IO is shared so you don't have to create an instance.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Chapters.txt")
    Debug.Print(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments.ToString)
    Dim count As Integer = GetCount(p)
    Console.WriteLine(count)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Private Function GetCount(Path As String) As Integer
    Dim s = File.ReadAllText(Path)
    Return s.Split().Length
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Split function, then Directly get the length of result array and add 1 to it.

Comment: The OP has that part done, it is the "i do not know how to open the file" part which is the problem.